# Observable WebService issue

Tags: java, web-services, jboss6.x, observable, observers

I want to make a Web Service(JAX-WS) that extends Observable and all of it's clients will implement Observer interface.

For some reasons I can't add a register method for this Web Service

```
@WebMethod
public void register(Observer o){
    this.addObserver(o);
}
```

Without this method, the WebService runs just fine on a JBoss EAP 6.1.

Having this method, the JBoss server will get this error:

> Failed to start service jboss."WS.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss."WS.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "WS.war"

Comment: You need a Web Service client to implement a specific interface?

Comment: @ramp, the client will be a desktop application that will register to the web service,

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you are trying to achieve or else your question is not complete, at least to me. You want an Observable pattern established between a WS and its clients ?

Comment: @ramp, yep, that is exactly what i want. I will have more than one client so I need a mechanism to send the information from the WS to all of the clients registered to it.